# Highschool Probability question.

Tags: probability

I have got a probability question where I'm stuck. The question says

> Two sisters differ by an age of $3$ years. Find the probability that at least one of them is born in leap year.

Assumption: The years are not century years and Gregorian leap years are considered

Now, the issue is, I've got $3$ different approaches which lead to $3$ different answers. I'll explain each of them right here,

1. > First one: Say, $S$ is sister $1$ and $S'$ is sister $2$. So, Say $S$ got a birthday in *leap year* that can be written in form $4m$. So, this renders us with $S$' having birthday in year $4m+3$, which is *not leap*. For next year, say $S$ got birthday in $4m+1$, which is *not leap*, so $S'$ got birthday in $4m+1+3$, which is of the form $4x$, which is *leap year*. Next year, birthday of $S$ is $4m+2$, (*not leap*), so, $S'$ has birthday, $4m+2+3$ i.e. of the form $4y+1$, *not leap*. Similarly, for next year, $S$ has birthday in $4m+3$, so $S'$ has birthday $4m+3+6$, i.e. $4z+1$, which is not leap. So, out of $4$ possible outcome, two are favourable, i.e. $2$ out of $4$ cases have at least one leap year. Which gives up, probability (at least one born in leap year) = $2/4 = 1/2$
  2.

> Here's another approach, let one of the sisters be not born in a leap year, say $x$. So, the other sister is born in $(x+3)$. Now, from the years $(x+1)$ or $(x+2)$ or $(x+3)$, one of them must be leap year. This gives us a $(1/3)$rd probability of at least one of them being born in a leap year.

3.

> And a third arbitrary way which gives me $2/3$rd probability. (Leap, Non leap), (Non leap, non leap) and (non leap, leap). So, $2/3$rd

Can someone help me figure out the right way and hence the right answer?

Comment: The rules aren't clear.  More specifically, the relation with the leap year rules aren't clear.  The [leap year rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year) are more complicated than people imagine.  What (exact)  rules did you intend?

Comment: @lulu Can you tell me the right approach to the above-stated question?

Comment: As I said, rather clearly I thought, the question can not be answered as it stands.  Is it likely that the sisters were born near a year which is a multiple of $100$ but not a multiple of $400$?  Please look up the leap year rules I linked to and modify your question to address those.

Comment: @lulu What if we rather look at the question in a plain way? Assuming that the years are not century years which need to be divisible by 400.

Comment: Please edit your post accordingly.

Comment: But, if all you mean by "leap year" is "a year divisible by $4$" then the problem is entirely trivial.  The eldest sister was born in a year which is one of $\{0,1,2,3\}\pmod 4$ with equal probability.

Comment: @lulu I beg you pardon but can you please put it in simpler words for me to understand? I'm a highschooler.

Comment: Sure. Assuming "leap year" just means "a year divisible by $4$" then look at the year the elder sister was born.  It's of one of the forms $4n, 4n+1,4n+2,4n+3$ with equal probability.  You have a success in two of those cases, so the answer is $\frac 12$.

Comment: @lulu Right, I got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approach 1 is correct.

Approach 2 is solving a different problem, which is "if the first sister is born in a non-leap year, what is the chance the second sister is born in a leap year."

Approach 3 is just wrong (even if you correct the list to include (non leap, non leap) and remove the duplicate) because it assumes that the three possibilities have equal probability.  In fact (non leap, non leap) is twice as likely as the others.

Comment: What can be another way to intuit this question? Like, what if I was list out random years and note my observations, should that lead me to half of the times getting at least one leap as I increase the number of observations?

Comment: Absolutely it should.  lulu's comments to the question are saying exactly that.